# Express Session not saving when using $.ajax({});

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

Exactly as it says. I'm attempting to save some data an Express session, and Express is seemingly treating each AJAX request as a separate session, thus not saving my data.

On the client

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/orders',
  method: 'post',
  data: { item: item }
});
```

On the server

```
router.post('/orders', function(req, res) {
  var sess = req.session,
      order = sess.order || [],
      item = req.body.item || '',
      quantity = req.body.quantity || 1;

  if (!item) return res.status(404).end();

  if (order[item]) {
    order[item] += quantity;
  } else {
    order[item] = quantity;
  }

  //save our order to the session
  req.session.order = order;
  req.session.save();
  console.log(req.session.order); // verified that req.session.order is set

  return res.status(200).end();
});
```

This is NOT a CORS request - it's me hitting my local server from a locally running client.

Comment: do you have a `.success` callback?

Comment: I don't believe that matters, but even when I have one the behavior is the same.

Comment: I believe that session string should be sent with ajax request to server. For example, in HTTP Cookie header. Is it? Sometimes AJAX requests work with Postman extension but not in application. Can you try using Postman?

Comment: Interestingly enough, if you're session variable type is an array, it doesn't save its contents. All I had to do was set change `order = sess.order || []` to `order = sess.order || {}`

Comment: do u have `connection.sid` cookie on ur client side ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the code below to ur `$.ajax` config may solve the problem:

```
$.ajax({
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  ... // other settings
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using fetch worked for me, like below

```
fetch(url, { credentials: 'include',
             method: 'post',
             ...// other fetch configs
}).then(onsuccesscallback)
```

The key is including credentials when configuring fetch